# I just installed Garuda and I'm getting error when upgrading

Tags: arch-linux, upgrade, pacman, garuda-linux

I ran `sudo pacman -Syu`

I got this is error

```
error: key "45ECA705E3897524654A37880706B90D37D9B881" could not be looked up remotely
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/beautyline-20210621-1-any.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package(PGP signature)).
```

I refreshed keeys using `sudo pacman-key --refresh-keys`.
And also ran `sudo pacman -Sy archlinux-keyring`

Yet I'm getting same error.

Comment: Maybe a cleaning of the package cache would help: `sudo pacman -Sc`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I came across the same very problem today and managed to solve it using [this](https://forum.garudalinux.org/t/pacman-and-pamac-not-working-properly-for-me/9764/2) answer.

> You basically just need to install chaotic-keyring before all other packages as it contains the new signing key which is shown as unknown currently. (kind of a security measure) Then, you can proceed installing/updating.
>
> `sudo pacman -Sy chaotic-keyring && sudo pacman -Su`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I hate how stupidly hard they make it to use these arch distros :D